# Twilio - status call back - recording url

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I use statuscallbackurl to get the call details and post to another system. documentation says we can get the recording url from RecordingUrl the posted parameters.

But I do not get this url. My response xml is below. Let me know how to get the recording url.

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial action="url" callerId="+19999999999" timeout="15" sequential="true" record="true">
    <Number>+19999999999</Number>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I believe that the recording URL will only be sent to the URL you've specified in the `action` parameter.

From [the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-record):

*"...a RecordingUrl parameter will be sent to the 'action' URL on the associated  verb. You must set an 'action' URL to receive the RecordingUrl."*

I see that you've specified the `action` parameter.  Are you saying that the `RecordingUrl` parameter is not included in the request to that URL?

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have setup url in the Twilio->Numbers->Voice->Status Callback URL in the Twilio account.